# fluent-bit grep filter not working as expected

Tags: filter, grep, fluent-bit

I'm trying to filter the log by level, but it's not working as expected. Here is my sample log.

```
[1] sample: [1678822837.893110278, {"log"=>"{"Timestamp":"2023-03-15T03:40:37.8929481+08:00","Level":"Verbose","MessageTemplate":"This is Trace","Properties":{"ActionId":"2c8e96ec-7ea7-4bf5-bd8f-e692fecae4a7","RequestId":"0HMP4O98PRMG2:00000001","RequestPath":"/SampleLogging","SpanId":"|e8ff0813-405598a6b4fe004d.","TraceId":"e8ff0813-405598a6b4fe004d","ParentId":"","ConnectionId":"0HMP4O98PRMG2"}}"}]
[2] sample: [1678822837.893486359, {"log"=>"{"Timestamp":"2023-03-15T03:40:37.8933146+08:00","Level":"Debug","MessageTemplate":"This is Debug","Properties":{"ActionId":"2c8e96ec-7ea7-4bf5-bd8f-e692fecae4a7","RequestId":"0HMP4O98PRMG2:00000001","RequestPath":"/SampleLogging","SpanId":"|e8ff0813-405598a6b4fe004d.","TraceId":"e8ff0813-405598a6b4fe004d","ParentId":"","ConnectionId":"0HMP4O98PRMG2"}}"}]
[3] sample: [1678822837.893674630, {"log"=>"{"Timestamp":"2023-03-15T03:40:37.8935494+08:00","Level":"Information","MessageTemplate":"This is Information","Properties":{"ActionId":"2c8e96ec-7ea7-4bf5-bd8f-e692fecae4a7","RequestId":"0HMP4O98PRMG2:00000001","RequestPath":"/SampleLogging","SpanId":"|e8ff0813-405598a6b4fe004d.","TraceId":"e8ff0813-405598a6b4fe004d","ParentId":"","ConnectionId":"0HMP4O98PRMG2"}}"}]
[4] sample: [1678822837.893866881, {"log"=>"{"Timestamp":"2023-03-15T03:40:37.8937288+08:00","Level":"Warning","MessageTemplate":"This is Warning","Properties":{"ActionId":"2c8e96ec-7ea7-4bf5-bd8f-e692fecae4a7","RequestId":"0HMP4O98PRMG2:00000001","RequestPath":"/SampleLogging","SpanId":"|e8ff0813-405598a6b4fe004d.","TraceId":"e8ff0813-405598a6b4fe004d","ParentId":"","ConnectionId":"0HMP4O98PRMG2"}}"}]
[5] sample: [1678822837.894049382, {"log"=>"{"Timestamp":"2023-03-15T03:40:37.8939219+08:00","Level":"Error","MessageTemplate":"This is Error","Properties":{"ActionId":"2c8e96ec-7ea7-4bf5-bd8f-e692fecae4a7","RequestId":"0HMP4O98PRMG2:00000001","RequestPath":"/SampleLogging","SpanId":"|e8ff0813-405598a6b4fe004d.","TraceId":"e8ff0813-405598a6b4fe004d","ParentId":"","ConnectionId":"0HMP4O98PRMG2"}}"}]
[6] sample: [1678822837.894352233, {"log"=>"{"Timestamp":"2023-03-15T03:40:37.8941080+08:00","Level":"Fatal","MessageTemplate":"This is Fatal","Properties":{"ActionId":"2c8e96ec-7ea7-4bf5-bd8f-e692fecae4a7","RequestId":"0HMP4O98PRMG2:00000001","RequestPath":"/SampleLogging","SpanId":"|e8ff0813-405598a6b4fe004d.","TraceId":"e8ff0813-405598a6b4fe004d","ParentId":"","ConnectionId":"0HMP4O98PRMG2"}}"}]
```

I've tried the first command below but no output.

```
bin/fluent-bit -i tail \
  -p 'path=/home/user/app/logs/*.*' \
  -p 'tag=sample' \
  -F grep \
  -p 'regex=Level Warning|Error|Fatal' \
  -m '*' \
  -o stdout
```

Second try on the command below, but the information level log still passes through.

```
bin/fluent-bit -i tail \
  -p 'path=/home/user/app/logs/*.*' \
  -p 'tag=sample' \
  -F grep \
  -p 'exclude=Level Information' \
  -m '*' \
  -o stdout
```

Any idea how can I use the `grep` filter in fluent-bit correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution to resolve this after some times. It's needed to include the `json` parser and using the record accessor.

```
bin/fluent-bit -R /etc/fluent-bit/parsers.conf \
  -i tail \
  -p 'path=/home/user/app/logs/*.*' \
  -p 'tag=sample' \
  -p parser=json \
  -F grep \
  -p 'regex=$Level Warning|Error|Fatal' \
  -m '*' \
  -o stdout
```